# How to pass class as parameter in Swift

Tags: json, class

In java , we can do this

```
public Object setClass(String JSONString, Class clazz){
  return JSON.parseObject(JSONString,clazz)
}
```

But in Swift,what should I do to pass class as paramter .Just like

```
public func decodeData(dataValue : Data, decodeClass: AnyClass){
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(decodeClass, from: dataValue)
            let resultData = json.info;
        }catch{

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use generics as in here:

```
    func decode<T: Decodable>(data: Data, type: T.Type){
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
        } catch {
            //
        }
    }
```

And when you want to call, you can use `.self` notation:

```
decode(data: data, type: String.self)
decode(data: data, type: [String].self)
decode(data: data, type: [Int].self)
```